# Immutability in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, database-permissions

I want to create an immutable Postgres database, where the user can insert & select (write & read) data, but cannot update or delete the data.

I am aware of the `FOR UPDATE` lock, but I don't understand how to use it.

Let's say for example I have the table below, how can I make it immutable (or, if I understood correctly, how can I use the `FOR UPDATE` lock permanently)

```sql
CREATE TABLE account(
 user_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
 username VARCHAR (50) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
 password VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
 email VARCHAR (355) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
 created_on TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
 last_login TIMESTAMP
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, that  solution doesn't work. I found this one. I make a *before* trigger on the table *on update for each row*:

```sql
create or replace function table_update_guard() returns trigger
language plpgsql immutable parallel safe cost 1 as $body$
begin
  raise exception
    'trigger %: updating is prohibited for %.%',
    tg_name, tg_table_schema, tg_table_name
    using errcode = 'restrict_violation';
  return null;
end;
$body$;

create or replace trigger account_update_guard
before update on account for each row
execute function table_update_guard();
```

See my original [research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75104505/postgres-how-to-generically-make-a-column-immutable/75104506#75104506).

Answer (score 9):

The solution is to give the user that accesses the database only the `INSERT` and `SELECT` privilege on the tables involved.

A lock is not a tool to deny somebody access, but a short-time barrier to prevent conflicting data modifications to happen at the same time.

Here is an example:

```
CREATE TABLE sensitive (
   id bigint GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
   available text,
   restricted text
);
```

Now I want to allow `someuser` to insert data and read and update all columns except `restricted`, and I want to keep myself from deleting data in that table:

```
/* the CREATE TABLE above was run by user "laurenz" */
REVOKE DELETE ON sensitive FROM laurenz;

GRANT INSERT ON sensitive TO someuser;
GRANT SELECT (id, available), UPDATE (id, available) ON sensitive TO someuser;
```

Comment: Nope, it didn't work for me.

Comment: "It didn't work" doesn't give me a handle to figure out where you went wrong. Look at `\dp table_name` in `psql`.

Comment: I went wrong nowhere. Take a look at a couple of the first lines: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75104506/2634207

Comment: You must have gone wrong. The best I can do is add some sample code to my answer to show how it is done.

Comment: Would you please? I'd like to learn

Comment: I have added an example.