# postgres: How to generically make a column immutable?

Tags: postgresql, dynamic, plpgsql, datatrigger

Here's the problem.

```sql
create table customer (
  customer_id int generated by default as identity (start with 100) primary key
);
create table cart (
  cart_id int generated by default as identity (start with 100) primary key
);
```

I want to protect `customer_id` **and** `cart_id` from updating **generically** once they are inserted. How?

---

**UPD:** While I was writing the question I found the answer to my original question. Here it is:

```
create table cart (
  cart_id int generated by default as identity (start with 100) primary key,
  name text not null,
  at timestamp with time zone
);

create or replace function table_update_guard() returns trigger
language plpgsql immutable parallel safe cost 1 as $body$
begin
  raise exception
    'trigger %: updating is prohibited for %',
    tg_name, tg_argv[0]
    using errcode = 'restrict_violation';
  return null;
end;
$body$;

create or replace trigger cart_update_guard
before update of cart_id, name on cart for each row
-- NOTE: the WHEN clause below is optional
when (
     old.cart_id is distinct from new.cart_id
  or old.name    is distinct from new.name
)
execute function table_update_guard('cart_id, name');

> insert into cart (cart_id, name) values (0, 'prado');
INSERT 0 1
> update cart set cart_id = -1 where cart_id = 0;
ERROR:  trigger cart_update_guard: updating is prohibited for cart_id, name
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function table_update_guard() line 3 at RAISE
> update cart set name = 'nasa' where cart_id = 0;
ERROR:  trigger cart_update_guard: updating is prohibited for cart_id, name
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function table_update_guard() line 3 at RAISE
> update cart set at = now() where cart_id = 0;
UPDATE 1
```

The `WHEN` clause was suggested by [Belayer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7623856/belayer) in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75128563/2634207). The full explanation is in my [research](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75104506/2634207). Additionally I examined [the approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75132753/2634207) with playing with privileges. **NOTE:** Some people say that triggers like here are performance killers. They are wrong. How do you think postgres implements constraints internally? — Using implicit triggers like defined here.

Comment: All you have to do is to `REVOKE` the `UPDATE` privilege from yourself, that is, the user that created and owns the table.

Comment: Hmmm...  It looks like I wasn't clear enough in the very first attempt in the answer below. I exactly did what you say and voilà, failed.

Comment: You revoked a privilege that was never granted (`UPDATE` on the column `customer_id`). Such a `REVOKE` has no effect. Instead, you have to `REVOKE UPDATE` **on the whole table** and then grant it on all the columns you need. Look at `\dp customer` in `psql` to see the actual permissions.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, I examined your suggestion in [the new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75132753/2634207) below. Thank you for your point.

Comment: Then you have figured out that a trigger is not the best way to do this, right? You just have to remember to grant privileges for every column you add. A trigger is bad for performance and unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, nope, I found a trigger is the best way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### TL;DR

What did I try? Revoking `UPDATE` privilege doesn't work.

```sql
# \c danissimo danissimo
You are now connected to database "danissimo" as user "danissimo".

> revoke update (customer_id) on customer from danissimo;
REVOKE
> insert into customer (customer_id) values (0);
INSERT 0 1
> update customer set customer_id = 0 where customer_id = 0;
UPDATE 1
> update customer set customer_id = -1 where customer_id = 0;
UPDATE 1
```

Okay, let's put a guard on it.

```sql
create or replace function customer_id_guard() returns trigger
language plpgsql as $body$
begin
  if old.customer_id != new.customer_id then
    raise exception
      'trigger %: updating is prohibited for %',
      tg_name, 'customer_id' using
      errcode = 'restrict_violation';
  end if;
  return new;
end;
$body$;

create or replace trigger customer_id_guard
after update on customer for each row
execute function customer_id_guard();
```

Now let's give them some work.

```sql
> update customer set customer_id = -1 where customer_id = -1;
UPDATE 1
```

Right, I didn't change the value. What about this:

```sql
> update customer set customer_id = 0 where customer_id = -1;
ERROR:  trigger customer_id_guard: updating is prohibited for customer_id
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function customer_id_guard() line 4 at RAISE
```

Yeah, here it goes. Good, let's protect `cart_id` as well. I don't want to copy–paste trigger functions, so I let's try to generalize it:

```sql
create or replace function generated_id_guard() returns trigger
language plpgsql as $body$
declare
  id_col_name text := tg_argv[0];
  equal boolean;
begin
  execute format('old.%1$I = new.%1$I', id_col_name) into equal;
  if not equal then
    raise exception
      'trigger %: updating is prohibited for %',
      tg_name, id_col_name using
      errcode = 'restrict_violation';
  end if;
  return new;
end;
$body$;

create or replace trigger cart_id_guard
after update on cart for each row
execute function generated_id_guard('cart_id');
```

As you might notice I pass the column name to the trigger function and generate an expression and put the result of that expression into `equal` which then test.

```sql
> insert into cart (cart_id) values (0);
INSERT 0 1
> update cart set cart_id = 0 where cart_id = 0;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "old"
LINE 1: old.cart_id = new.cart_id
        ^
QUERY:  old.cart_id = new.cart_id
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function generated_id_guard() line 6 at EXECUTE
```

Hmmm... He's right, what the dangling `old.cart_id = new.cart_id`? What if I write

```sql
execute format('select old.%1$I = new.%1$I', id_col_name) into equal;

> update cart set cart_id = 0 where cart_id = 0;
ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "old"
LINE 1: select old.cart_id = new.cart_id
               ^
QUERY:  select old.cart_id = new.cart_id
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function generated_id_guard() line 6 at EXECUTE
```

Right, right... What if I write

```sql
declare
  id_old int;
  id_new int;
begin
  execute format('select %I from old', id_col_name) into id_old;
  execute format('select %I from new', id_col_name) into id_new;
  if id_old != id_new then

> update cart set cart_id = 0 where cart_id = 0;
ERROR:  relation "old" does not exist
LINE 1: select cart_id from old
                            ^
QUERY:  select cart_id from old
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function generated_id_guard() line 7 at EXECUTE
```

Aha, «relation "old" does not exist»...

Well, here's the last resort:

```sql
drop table cart;
create table cart (
  cart_id int generated by default as identity (start with 100) primary key,
  at timestamp with time zone
);
insert into cart (cart_id) values (0);

create or replace function surrogate_id_guard() returns trigger
language plpgsql immutable parallel safe cost 1 as $body$
begin
  raise exception
    'trigger %: updating is prohibited for %',
    tg_name, tg_argv[0] using
    errcode = 'restrict_violation';
  return null;
end;
$body$;

create or replace trigger cart_id_guard
before update of cart_id on cart for each row
execute function surrogate_id_guard('cart_id');
```

I just make it trigger on any attempt to update `cart_id`. Let's check:

```sql
> update cart set cart_id = 0 where cart_id = 0;
ERROR:  trigger cart_id_guard: updating is prohibited for cart_id
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function surrogate_id_guard() line 3 at RAISE
> update cart set at = now() where cart_id = 0;
UPDATE 1
```

Well, finally I answered my original question at this point. But another question is still arisen: How to apply the same algorithm encoded in a function to columns given in args to that function?

Comment: note: you cannot to lost any rights when you are owner of table. This is reason why revoking update "doesn't" work in your case. It is good practice to use different owner of database objects than application's users.

Comment: @PavelStehule, that is exactly the point. The owner of a table is still able to update it. And yes, you're right it's better to send another user to dig into the DB in the name of the app. But... there're a lot of other complicated things I have to address, so... there is one for now yet

Comment: ok. But your design can be pretty slow. Probably faster can be transformation of new, old variables to jsonb and check of equality in via comparing of jsonb field.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you want to prevent any user from modifying the the table id once it is established and to have a generic function produce the exception, while still allowing other updates. You can accomplish this by modifying the trigger rather than the function. Specify the WHEN predicate on the trigger itself. For the `cart` table then:

```
create or replace trigger cart_id_guard
   before update of cart_id 
       on cart for each row
          when (old.cart_id is distinct from new.cart_id)
       execute function surrogate_id_guard('cart_id');
```

The for the `customer` table the trigger becomes:

```
create or replace trigger customer_id_guard
   before update of customer_id 
       on customer for each row
     when (old.customer_id is distinct from new.customer_id)
  execute function surrogate_id_guard('customer_id');
```

The trigger function itself does not change. ([demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/mJ22CUui))

Comment: Great improvement, thank you, @Belayer

Answer (score 0):

The very first attempt in my [previous research](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75104506/2634207) was to revoke privileges. As [Laurenz Albe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6464308/laurenz-albe) pointed in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75104505/postgres-how-to-generically-make-a-column-immutable/75128563#comment132539755_75104505) I had to revoke the privilege to update the whole table instead of revoking the privilege to update a certain column. Here's the code:

```
# \c danissimo danissimo
You are now connected to database "danissimo" as user "danissimo".

create table cart (
  cart_id int generated by default as identity (start with 100) primary key,
  at timestamp with time zone default now()
);
insert into cart default values;

revoke update on cart from danissimo;
```

Can I update the table now?

```
> update cart set at = at - interval '1 day';
ERROR:  permission denied for table cart
```

Okay, let's grant the privilege to update columns other than `cart_id`:

```
> grant update (at) on cart to danissimo;
> update cart set at = at - interval '1 day';
UPDATE 1
```

So far, so good. Now time ticks and eventually danissimo adds another column `item_ids`:

```
alter table cart add column item_ids int[];
```

Can danissimo update the new column now? Keep in mind that the privilege to update the whole table was revoked from him and the privilege to update the new column was not granted:

```
> update cart set item_ids = array[1, 3, 7 ,5];
ERROR:  permission denied for table cart
```

And if I grant him the privilege?

```
> grant update (item_ids) on cart to danissimo;
> update cart set item_ids = array[1, 3, 7 ,5];
UPDATE 1
```

What does that all mean? I considered two approaches. One is to prohibit updates of a column once a value is given to the column. Another is to play with privileges. In our projects it's usual that we add new columns while the projects evolve. If I stick with privileges I have to grant the privilege to update the new column each time I add a new one. On the other hand, if I protect some columns with a trigger I just add new columns and bother no more.

**CONCLUSION:** Use triggers as shown above .

Answer (score 0):

I was able to implement initial trigger idea with function that could be re-used.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION forbid_column_change() RETURNS TRIGGER
LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $body$
DECLARE
  is_equal BOOL;
  id_col_name TEXT := TG_ARGV[0];
BEGIN
  EXECUTE FORMAT('
    SELECT $1.%1$I IS NOT DISTINCT FROM $2.%1$I',
    id_col_name
  ) INTO is_equal USING OLD, NEW;


  IF NOT is_equal THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION
      'trigger %: updating is forbidden for %.%.%',
      TG_NAME, TG_TABLE_SCHEMA, TG_TABLE_NAME, id_col_name
      USING
        ERRCODE = 'restrict_violation';
  END IF;

  RETURN NEW;
END;
$body$;
```

```
CREATE TRIGGER column_guard
  BEFORE UPDATE OF col_name ON table
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE FUNCTION forbid_column_change('col_name');
```

Important note, that function must be defined without args, function trigger args go to TG_ARGV.